# Expected Undefined to be an object for Node Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

what the heck am I doing wrong here.  Isn't a function an object in JS?

**car.js**

```
'use strict';


var Car = function(){

};

export default Car;
```

**car-test.js**

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {Car} from '../../src/car';

describe('car', () => {

    it('should have a car to work with', () => {
        expect(Car).to.be.an('object');
    });

});
```

UPDATE

I could even just leave the var out, not sure if that makes a difference, the var is still pointing to the same thing but I could also do this:

```
function Car(){

};

export default Car;
```

Comment: Your import is wrong, that's why `Car` is `undefined`. It should be `import Car from '../../src/car';`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a/an` tests the `typeof` value for the item. Yes, functions are objects, but their `typeof` is `"function"`.

This is just about the only place where `typeof` gives us more detailed information than just `"object"` for an object (in fact, I can't think of another one; `typeof new Date` is `"object"`, `typeof` a regexp object is `"object"`, etc.). `typeof` is fairly vague, but was specific in this one situation. :-) FWIW, I cover type checking a bit on my anemic little blog: [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html)

Comment: so this is where I'm missing fundamentals then.  Isn't a function an object in JS?

Comment: ok cool.  So I want to be sure I can work with it...so should I use the new keyword to get this test to pass?

Comment: @WTF: Only if you want to A) Instantiate a `car`, and B) Throw an error (instead of failing a test) if `car` isn't a function. Why not `expect(car).to.be.a('function');`?

Comment: because I'm testing for objects not functions...this is a node module

Comment: I'm using it as an object.

Comment: @WTF: It doesn't matter that it's a node module. You're importing `Car`, specifically. `Car` is a function. So... I don't know Mocha enough to suggest it, but presumably there's a way to say "it's a function or an object"?

Comment: ok so the only reason I'd want to instantiate it is if in my car.js I added some prototype functions or something and so there'd be a need to instantiate it if that were the case right?  In this case I don't have anything on its prototype so probably doesn't make sense to create instances of it??

Comment: @WTF: Totally depends on what you're testing. Anyway, this is why the test was failing, `typeof car` is `"function"`. So just adjust as you think appropriate. :-)

Comment: Note that the test outcome seems to be "Expected Undefined to be an object". The OP is not importing `Car` correctly.